# Transfer condition modification

Tags: solidity, address.transfer, transfer, transferfrom

I am trying to add a condition that when the token is sold, change the fees to 7, in case it is a purchase, leave it at 1. Would the code shown be correct? In any case, what would be the best practice?

```js
function _transfer(address from, address _to, uint256 _value) private {
     if(to==msg.sender) {
         taxfee=7
         balances[from] = balances[from].sub(_value);
         balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
         emit Transfer(from, _to, _value);
     }
     else {
        taxfee=1
        balances[from] = balances[from].sub(_value);
        balances[_to] = balances[_to].add(_value);
        emit Transfer(from, _to, _value);
     }
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by sold/purchase?

Comment: I'll consider that `from` is selling  and `to` is buying. I think you might be considering the case when one of the parties is the "token pair". In that case I'll consider from=tokenPair then `to` is buying, to=tokenPair, then `from` is selling.